# Firebase - Search a child by value

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

Let's say I have this data on my Firebase:

`https://mygame.firebaseio.com/player`

```
{
  "player": {
    "bloodgulf01": {
      "username": "bloodgulf01",
      "uid": "twitter:102032",
      "level": 2,
      "map": 3,
      "x": 51,
      "y": 12
    },
    "damjanovic": {
      "username": "damjanovic",
      "uid": "github:77371",
      "level": 5,
      "map": 2,
      "x": 21,
      "y": 44
    }
  }
}
```

How would I search by `uid` and get that result's `snapshot`?

**Here's what I have tried:**

```
new Firebase("https://mygame.firebaseio.com/player")
    .startAt(authData.uid)
    .endAt(authData.uid)
    .once('value', function(snap) {
       console.log('accounts matching UID of ' + authData.uid, snap.val())
    });
```

Which returns: `accounts matching UID of github:123456789 null` despite having the `uid` inside that data of `/player/`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, everything in Firebase is an url. So you can just do this to get the data you want:

```
'https://mygame.firebaseio.com/player/' + uid
```

Comment: Yes but they aren't stored as UIDs but rather player usernames

Comment: @DanF Why don't you store the username under the uid instad of the opposite? Since the uid is always unique this is a better option than storing the keys as player names.

Comment: @Chrilliewoodz I suppose but then I wouldn't know how to search for usernames... in the database.

Answer (score 4):

Order by the child you want to filter on and then filter:

```
new Firebase("https://mygame.firebaseio.com/player")
  .orderByChild('uid')
  .equalTo(authData.uid)
  .once('child_added', function(snap) {
     console.log('account matching UID of ' + authData.uid, snap.val())
  });
```

Since you only expect a single player, you can probably get by with `once('child_added'`. If you need to handle potentially multiple players with the same uid, then:

```
  .on('child_added', function(snap) {
     console.log('account matching UID of ' + authData.uid, snap.val())
  });
```

Or

```
  .once('value', function(snap) {
     snap.forEach(function(child) {
       console.log('account matching UID of ' + authData.uid, child.val())
     });
  });
```

I am with Chrillewoodz on the structure though: I would **always** expect to see the `uid` as the key for a collection of users. You could search for the name with the approach above in that case.