# Firebase search by child value KOTLIN

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase realtime database structure [image]

I want to retrieve all questions with QID = "PQ1" . What i tried is given below . Its result is null .

```
database.child("Question").child("QID").equalTo("PQ1").limitToFirst(200).get().addOnSuccessListener {
Log.i("12345", "Got value ${it.value}")
}
```

My references :

[Firebase - Search a child by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361746/firebase-search-a-child-by-value)

[Firebase search by child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471284/firebase-search-by-child-value)

[Search firebase by Child of child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172633/search-firebase-by-child-of-child-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `database.child("Question").child("QID")` looks for a child node at path `/Question/QID` in your database, which doesn't exist and thus explains why you get an empty snapshot.

---

To query the Firebase Realtime Database needs two steps:

1. You [order all child nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data) on a property, on their key, or on their value by calling on of the `orderBy...` methods.
2. You then [filter the ordered child nodes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data) by calling one or more of the `equalTo`, `startAt`, `startAfter`, `endAt`, `endBefore`, `limitToFirst` and/or `limitToLast` methods.

While you're doing #2, you're not ordering the nodes first by calling `orderBy...`.

The correct code:

```
database.child("Question").orderByChild("QID").equalTo("PQ1").limitToFirst(200).get().addOnSuccessListener {
    Log.i("12345", "Got value ${it.value}")
}
```

Also don't forget that executing a query will potentially have multiple results, so the snapshot in `it.value` contains a list of those results and you will need to [iterate over its children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#kotlin+ktx_2). Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: thank you for your response , i tried the above code sorry to say that it doesn't worked

Comment: "doesn't worked" is really hard to help with. Is there an error message? If not: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: problem resolved thanks a lot for your effort